# NG-repeat display the value only once in td

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this table with ng-repeat. All I  want is to display one the value only once inside the ng-repeat.

My ng-repeat in tr

```
<tr ng-repeat="xx in results " >
     <tr>{{xx.id}}</tr>
     <tr>{{xx.invoicenumber}}</tr>
 </tr>
```

Here's my table

| ID | INVOICE# |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 112 |
| 1 | 113 |
| 1 | 114 |
| 2 | 115 |
| 2 | 116 |

Desired Output

| ID | INVOICE# |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 112 |
|  | 113 |
|  | 114 |
| 2 | 115 |
|  | 116 |

Answer (score 0):

@SprakenDude , Can you also share us the details about how and what is the structure of data you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Invoice Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="xx in results " >
        <td>{{printXXId(xx.id)}}</td>
        <td>{{xx.invoicenumber}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.preid=-1;

$scope.printXXId=function(id){
    return $scope.preid==id?'':$scope.preid=id;
}

$scope.results=[
    {
        id:1,
        invoicenumber:112
    },
    {
        id:1,
        invoicenumber:113
    },
    {
        id:1,
        invoicenumber:114
    },
    {
        id:2,
        invoicenumber:115
    },
    {
        id:2,
        invoicenumber:116
    },
]
 
   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```